# gdal.Warp produces black stripe

Tags: raster, gdal, osgeo

I have a TIFF file which looks like this:

[image]

Now I want to change the resolution by gdal.Warp. The script is the following:

```
gdal.Warp('output.tif',
      'input.tif',
      xRes=0.7, yRes=0.7)
```

And the output result is the following:

[image]

because of this black stripe on the right side, everything becomes very light. Can anyone help to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

You could try to cut out the last pixel line by defining a target extent that has one pixel width smaller `xmax` with `-te` https://gdal.org/programs/gdalwarp.html.

> -te <xmin ymin xmax ymax>
>
> Set georeferenced extents of output file to be created (in target SRS
> by default, or in the SRS specified with -te_srs)

I suppose that the last pixels have now their centers outside the area of the original image and resampling makes them black because the majority of source data is nodata.